# scalajs + uirouter how use it in the right way

Tags: angularjs, scala, angular-ui-router, scala.js

I'm try to start with scala.js and Angular. For that I'm using greencatsoft/scalajs-angular (https://github.com/greencatsoft/scalajs-angular) port

I found also a good sample https://github.com/josdirksen/smartjava/tree/master/scalajs

This sample is using "classic" `routeProvider`

```
routeProvider
   .when("/home", Route(HomeController))
```

*but I would use the **StateProvider**.*

I included the dependecies:

`jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "angular-ui-router" % "0.2.14" / "angular-ui-router.js" dependsOn "angular.js"`

an of cures also in my scala-module:

```
val module = Angular.module("helloworld",Seq("ui.router","mm.foundation"))
```

**Usage**:

```
override def initialize() {
    stateProvider
      .state("home", State(
            url="/home"
          , templateUrl = "myTest.html"
        )
      )
  }
```

But there was no way to "activate" the state.

1. I'missing in the `State apply` the possibility to add a *Controller*. Unclear for my why or how
2. I added the controller in the html  `< div ng-controller="DataController">`

any Idea?